# How do I stop receiving news for some accounts?

Tags: nintendo-switch

In order to buy a Japanese game, I went and created a Japanese Nintendo Account for my Switch.

Ever since then, I've been receiving a ton of Japanese news, along with the usual non-Japanese news, many of which are duplicates.

I would like to stop receiving news for my Japanese account only. Is it possible, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

According to a Q&A on the [Nintendo Support Forums](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/73337/~/us-switch-getting-japanese-news-feed), the only way to completely stop the Japanese channels from appearing in the news feed is to do a factory reset and not associate the Japanese account. While this is not the solution you are looking for, can reduce the amount of Japanese channels that will come through.

> While the Japanese news stories will not stop unless you do a factory reset without attaching a Japanese account, you can "slow it down" by disabling some non-English language News by using the following steps to un-follow the channels:
>
> From the HOME Menu, select "System Settings" > "System" > "News Channel >Settings."
>
> Deselect any non-English channels that you are following.
>
> This won't stop all the Japanese news, but may slow it down for you.